# Highlighting selected text and getting the occurrence at the same time

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JavaScript and is trying to write a simple highlighter tool. Each function works fine on their own, however when combining, the occurrence number doesn't work properly anymore. Here is my code, http://jsfiddle.net/mrBXu/, the problem is when you select any "The" at the first time, the occurrence works fine, however if you re select it, it's not right anymore. Thanks ahead for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is not that easy. The reason why it doesn't work on the second try is because you inserted a span to do a highlight. First time you select a text, your startContainer is a textNode that's inside a "p" tag. Second time you select, your startContainer is a textNode that starts at the end of span that you inserted. What you need to do will require more code. You need to not only check the startContainer, but also find its relationship to the "p" tag, and check all the nodes before the startContainer inside the "p" tag.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mrBXu/4/

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, however, it is still too hard for me to implement from scratch, is it possible that you can give me some example? Thanks!

Comment: I updated your code to work correctly. It's not very pretty, but it gets the job done.